# progaurd_properties.txt to Obfuscate the src code of android library project

Tags: android, proguard

I want to ship a android lib project but want to restrict access to the src code. So I am hoping to use the following technique:

1. Take the jar from the bin folder and place it in the libs folder.
2. Delete the src folder.

But I would like to Obfuscate the code before it is built into a jar. I understand that this can be achieved via proguard but I am confused about its usage. 
I just want Obfuscate all the src code. Could someone please help me with what all i need to put in proguard_properties.txt so that I could achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `proguard.config=proguard_properties.txt` to your `project.properties` file.
More information you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).

Comment: Thanks. But what do i write in the proguard_properties.txt file?

Comment: This is prepared config file for Proguard with default settins. If you want to change settings you can read official documentation http://proguard.sourceforge.net/

Comment: THe prepared config file is blank with everything commented...would that work?

Comment: Yes, another one - you need to build in release mode, not in debug.